# Google App Engine - Basic Cookie Handling with URLFetch

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cookies, webapp2, urlfetch

Experts,

It seems that retrieving even the most basic websites using google app engine can be quite challenging!

In my case I would like to retrieve the website at this url:

http://tdbank.mortgagewebcenter.com/PowerSite/CheckRates.aspx/Index/9809

I would like to accept all of the cookies and then POST a response to this url (this is a simple form post):

http://tdbank.mortgagewebcenter.com/PowerSite/CheckRates.aspx/Search

The string I would like to POST is:

```
'POSTDATA': 'Q585=1&Q2926=1&Q586=200000&Q587=240000&Q588=&Q9166=07071&Q591=1&Q592=1&Q594=3&searchButton=Search'
```

The problem I am getting is that the webpage is stating that 'Cookies are not enabled' on my web browser.

As you can see from the code below I tried manually adding cookies however this was not successful.

Please help!
-Todd

```
import cgi
import webapp2
import gzip
import StringIO

from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
#        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
        url = "http://tdbank.mortgagewebcenter.com/PowerSite/CheckRates.aspx/Index/9809"
        result = urlfetch.fetch(url,
                                headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B206 Safari/7534.48.3',
                                                 'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
                                                 'Accept-Language': 'en-us',
                                                 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
                                                 'Connection': 'keep-alive'})

        cookie = result.headers.get('set-cookie')
        input_text = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B206 Safari/7534.48.3',
                      'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
                      'Accept-Language': 'en-us',
                      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
                      'Connection': 'keep-alive',
                      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                      'Content-Length': '97',
                      'POSTDATA': 'Q585=1&Q2926=1&Q586=200000&Q587=240000&Q588=&Q9166=07071&Q591=1&Q592=1&Q594=3&searchButton=Search',
                      'SiteProfile':'ProfileId=9809',
                      's_sess':'c_m=undefinedfeedity.comfeedity.com; s_sq=; s_cc=true;;',
                      'bhCookieSaveSess':'1',
                      'bhPrevResults':'bhjs=1&bhrf=http://www.google.com/'}

        input_text['set-cookie'] = cookie
##        self.response.out.write(input_text)

        url2 = "http://tdbank.mortgagewebcenter.com/PowerSite/CheckRates.aspx/Search"
        result2 = urlfetch.fetch(url2, method='POST',headers=input_text)

#        self.response.out.write(result.headers)
        f = StringIO.StringIO(result2.content)
        c = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=f)
        content = c.read()
        self.response.out.write(content)
#        self.response.out.write(result.content)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)],
                              debug=True)
```

yaml file:

```
application: fimrates
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: fimrates.app
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually setting the cookie with your code. Here is an amended version of your code.

```
#import this module to be able to create a cookie
import Cookie

class BankHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    #put this function to create the cookie header
    def createCookieHeader(self, cookie):
        cookieHeader = ""
        for value in cookie.values():
            cookieHeader += "%s=%s; " % (value.key, value.value)
        return cookieHeader

    def get(self):
        ...
        self.cookie = Cookie.SimpleCookie() #create the cookie

        result = urlfetch.fetch({...,
                       #inject the cookie header                                                 
                      'Cookie': self.createCookieHeader(self.cookie)})

        cookie = result.headers.get('set-cookie', '')
        input_text = {...}

        #the header is 'Cookie' 
        input_text['Cookie'] = cookie

        url2 = "http://tdbank.mortgagewebcenter.com/PowerSite/CheckRates.aspx/Search"
        result2 = urlfetch.fetch(url2, method='POST',headers=input_text)
        ...
```